# How is the sicp cons-stream implemented?

Tags: scheme, sicp

I'm working through the streams section of the scip and am stuck on how to define a stream.

The following is my code:

```
(define (memo-func function)
  (let ((already-run? false)
        (result false))
    (lambda ()
      (if (not already-run?)
          (begin (set! result (function))
                 (set! already-run? true)
                 result)
          result))))


(define (delay exp)
  (memo-func (lambda () exp)))

(define (force function)
  (function))

(define the-empty-stream '())
(define (stream-null? stream) (null? stream))
(define (stream-car stream) (car stream))
(define (stream-cdr stream) (force (cdr stream)))

(define (cons-stream a b) (cons a (memo-func (lambda () b))))
```

If I define integers the way that the book descibes:

```
(define (integers-starting-from n)
   (cons-stream n (integers-starting-from (+ n 1))))
(define integers (integers-starting-from 1))
```

I get a message saying: Aborting!: maximum recursion depth exceeded.

I'm guessing that the *delay* function is not working but I don't know how to fix it. I am running the MIT scheme on my Mac.

### update 1

So now with cons-stream as a macro, the integers can be defined.

But then I've got another error.

```
(define (stream-take n s)
  (cond ((or (stream-null? s)
             (= n 0)) the-empty-stream)
        (else (cons-stream (stream-car s)
                           (stream-take (- n 1) (stream-cdr s))))))

(stream-take 10 integers)
;ERROR - Variable reference to a syntactic keyword: cons-stream
```

### update 2

Please ignore *update 1* above

Comment: I am the author of SRFI-41 Streams, which provides a different type of stream than SICP (and explains the difference). See it at the SRFI website (http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-41/) or my blog (http://programmingpraxis.com/2013/01/29/essay-srfi-41-streams/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`cons-stream` needs to be a macro in order for your sample code to work correctly. Otherwise the invocation of `cons-stream` will evaluate all its arguments eagerly.

Try this (not tested):

```
(define-syntax cons-stream
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((cons-stream a b)
     (cons a (memo-func (lambda () b))))))
```

P.S. Your `delay` needs to be a macro also, for similar reasons. Then after you fix `delay`, you can make your `cons-stream` use `delay` directly.

Comment: actually, I know what happened. I forgot to re-evaluate cons-stream with the changed cons-stream definition

Comment: Here's a breadcrumb for SICP newcomers or around-goers like me. The following article amounts to a mini-seminar on a `delay` without destructive update, showing its advantages and disadvantages: https://github.com/VincentToups/emacs-utils/blob/master/delay.md

It's the first such discussion that I found. It seems sufficient. For all that I know, the matter of why we might use destructive update in `delay` may be addressed well in SICP itself. It may also be addressed well somewhere on Stack Overflow or programmers.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot define delay as a function, since prior to calling it, Scheme will evaluate its argument - which is exactly what you're trying to postpone. SICP says this explicitly that delay should be a special form.