# Why is it legal in a function definition to make self-call but illegal for a value?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket, sicp

Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs (SICP) 3.5.2 introduces infinite streams:

```
(define ones
  (cons-stream 1 ones))
```

This code doesn't work in DrRacket, with the error:

> ones: undefined; cannot reference an identifier before its definition

Other code like this:

```
(define (integers-starting-from n)
  (cons-stream n
               (integers-starting-from (+ n 1))))

(define integers (integers-starting-from 1))
```

produce error:

> Interactions disabled

(fall in infinite loop?)

So far as I read(SICP), the key point of implementing an infinite stream is delayed evaluation:

```
(define (delay exp)
  (lambda () exp))

(define (cons-stream a b)
  (cons a
        (delay b)))
```

With this used in `cons-stream`, infinite stream still illegal.

Such data structure reminds me of recursive function in whose definition self-call is legal (in compiling) within or without an actual exit.

Why is it illegal for a value to reference itself? Even the reference has been delayed?

Could infinite stream supported by other programming language?

If not, is it about the way processor deal with assembly language? The data stack stuff?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14640833/how-is-the-sicp-cons-stream-implemented

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you make a procedure the arguments are already evaluated when you start the body of the procedure. Thus `delay` would not do anything since it's already computed at that time. `cons-stream` need to be a macro.

DrRacket is not one language implementation. It's an IDE that supports lots of languages. One of them is a SICP compatibility language. I mananged to run your code without errors using this code in DrRacket:

```scm
#!planet neil/sicp

(define ones
  (cons-stream 1 ones))

(define (integers-starting-from n)
  (cons-stream n
               (integers-starting-from (+ n 1))))

(define integers (integers-starting-from 1))
```

It works like a charm. The default language in DrRacket, `#!racket`, [has streams too](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/streams.html?q=stream-cons#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fstream..rkt%29._stream-cons%29%29), but the names are different:

```scm
#!racket 

(define ones
  (stream-cons 1 ones))

(define (integers-starting-from n)
  (stream-cons n
               (integers-starting-from (+ n 1))))

(define integers (integers-starting-from 1))
```

However for Scheme you should use SRFI-41 that you can use from both `#!racket` (using `(require srfi/41)`) and `#!r6rs` (and R7RS-large when it's finished)

```scm
(import (rnrs)
        (srfi :41))

(define ones
  (stream-cons 1 ones))

(define (integers-starting-from n)
  (stream-cons n
               (integers-starting-from (+ n 1))))

(define integers (integers-starting-from 1))
```

To roll your own SICP streams in both `#!racket` and `#!r6rs` you can use `define-syntax`

```scm
(define-syntax stream-cons 
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ a d) (cons a (delay d)))))
```

Note that RSFI-41 and rackets own stream library for `#!racket` delays both values in a `stream-cons` and not just the tail as in SICP version here.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the expression in a `define` is evaluated *before* the name is bound to a value. It tries to evaluate `(cons-stream 1 ones)` before `ones` is defined, causing an error.

The reason this works fine for functions is that the *body of a function is not evaluated* when the function is. That is, to evaluate `(lambda (x) (f x))`, the language returns a function without looking at its body. Since

```
(define (f x) (f x))
```

is syntax sugar for defining a lambda, the same logic applies.

Did you define `cons-stream` yourself as above? If you make `cons-stream` a normal function it won't work properly. Since Scheme is strict by default, arguments are evaluated *before* the function gets called. If `cons-stream` is a normal function, `b` would get evaluated completely before being passed to `delay`, making you hit an infinite loop.

`cons-stream` in SICP is a "special form" rather than a function, which means that it can control how its arguments are evaluated.

If you use the `stream-cons` and other `stream-` operations built into Racket, you'd get the behavior you want.

Finally, some other languages *do* allow values to reference themselves. A great example is Haskell, where this works because everything is *lazy by default*. Here's a Haskell snippet defining `ones` to be an infinite list of ones. (Since everything is lazy, Haskell lists behave just like Scheme streams):

```
ones = 1 : ones
```

Comment: Oh, I see. The `special form`, just like the `new-if` bug at exercise 1.6. Racket has already set the boundary for those `self defined` functions

Answer (score 1):

This definition works in Racket:

```
(define ones
  (cons-stream 1 ones))
```

…As long as you provide a delayed implementation of `cons-stream` as a special form, which is the whole point of section 3.5 in SICP:

```
(define-syntax cons-stream
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ head tail)
     (cons head (delay tail)))))
```

Comment: Is this `tail recursion`?

Comment: @Rahn It's a macro, not a tail-recursive procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answers above, to make sure the code run, you should also define `delay` like this:

```
(define-syntax delay
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ exp)
     (lambda () exp))))
```

`delay` as well as `cons-stream` has to be defined as a macro.

In another option, you could just call the `delay` predefined in Racket rather than building a new one.

But don't do this:

```
(define (delay exp)
  (lambda () exp))
```

The compiler would take your definition, thus the program crashes in evaluation:

> Interactions disabled