# failed to define a infinite stream of one, SICP

Tags: stream, scheme, infinite, sicp

In the book(*Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs* section 3.52, Chinese Version) ,we use code:

```
(define ones (cons-stream 1 ones))
```

to define a infinite stream of one.

But when I ran this, I got a `Unbound variable: ones` error. 
Why? Did I miss something?

[The part of English version of the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dSwY.png)

Comment: Hard to tell without more details (what book? what interpreter?), but I'd suggest you try using a different language or fiddle around with your interpreter's configuration, something is restricting references to undefined variables.

Comment: The book is the Chinese version of *Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs*. I just readed the English Version and upload the picture of the part of the book. I don't think it's because of the bad translation.@ÓscarLópez

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you did when you "ran this"? Did you enter the definition in the REPL? Did you load a file with the definition? Did you try to print `ones` after defining it? Something else?

Comment: You are right. I defined "cons-stream" as a lambda before I ran this. Thank you.

Comment: you know, you can mentally "inline" that macro, and just write `(define ones (lambda () (cons 1 ones)))`.

Comment: btw you need to undelete your answer and accept it, so all can see that the issue has been resolved. :)

Comment: `cons-stream` might need to be defined as a macro.  E.g., see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14640833/how-is-the-sicp-cons-stream-implemented.

Comment: Also see: [Why is it legal in a function definition to make self-call but illegal for a value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31896117/why-is-it-legal-in-a-function-definition-to-make-self-call-but-illegal-for-a-val?lq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I defined "cons-stream" as a lambda before I ran this. But "cons-stream" need to be a macro. :)