# Trouble implementing streams with Racket

Tags: stream, racket, lazy-sequences

I am working my way through the [Wizard Book](https://mitp-content-server.mit.edu/books/content/sectbyfn/books_pres_0/6515/sicp.zip/index.html) Structure and Interpretation of Programming in my free evenings. All was going well, until I tried to implement streams in Chapter Three. I am using (Dr)Racket, not Scheme, so this might be my problem.

The crux of the problem is that when I try to create streams I get a memory issue: "interactions disabled; out of memory". This suggests to me that there is something wrong with the way I am using delay.

Thanks in advance for any advice :)

I have tried the code suggested in the text:

```
#lang racket

(define (cons-stream a b)
  (cons a (delay b)))

(define (car-stream s)
  (car s))

(define (cdr-stream s)
  (force (cdr s)))
```

where I am calling Racket's delay and force. I have also tried implementing delay and force myself following the text, but I come across the same memory error.

To test that this is all working I tried writing an infinite stream of 1s:

```
(define (ones) (cons-stream 1 (ones)))
```

and a very large interval:

```
(define (interval low high)
  (if (> low high)
      null
      (cons-stream low
                   (interval (+ low 1) high))))

(define (first-integers n)
  (interval 0 n))

(define test-interval
  (first-integers 10000000000000000000000000))
```

To my understanding of the text, neither of these should cause problems because we only generate the streams when required. However, something I've done causes a memory issue and so I think the code tries to generate the entire stream!

Comment: Tip: Install the [`sicp` package](https://docs.racket-lang.org/sicp-manual/index.html) and use [`#lang sicp`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/sicp-manual/SICP_Language.html) instead of `#lang racket` when working through the exercises in the book

Comment: `cons-stream` needs to be implemented as a macro, not a function, iirc.

Comment: See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14640833/how-is-the-sicp-cons-stream-implemented

Comment: @Shawn thanks for the tips and link :) What does iirc mean?

Comment: If I Recall Correctly

Comment: The book does not suggest that `cons-stream` can be implemented as a procedure; it says that it is a *special form*.

Comment: See [footnote 56](https://mitp-content-server.mit.edu/books/content/sectbyfn/books_pres_0/6515/sicp.zip/full-text/book/book-Z-H-24.html#footnote_Temp_446).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can not define

```
(define (cons-stream a b)
  (cons a (delay b)))
```

because `define` creates a function `cons-stream`, so on every function call all arguments will be evaluated before the call is made. Which defeats the whole purpose -- `b` will be already evaluated.

See also [How is delay implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76257442/how-is-delay-implemented/76257777#76257777).